# Страница *.blazor - как получить параметры адресной строки

Tags: c#, razor

Есть некий файл RequestStatistics.blazor:

```
@page "/RequestStatistics"
 
... 
 
@code {    
...
}
```

Используется ASP.Net Core v. 3.2.1 Как в секции @code получить доступ к параметрам адреса?
Передавать параметр как часть адреса не получается, т.к. это должен быть e-mail, а он может содержать точки, и в этом случае возникает ошибка.
Request в коде недоступен или я не знаю, как его правильно создать.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете попробовать сделать так:

```cs
@page "/test"

<h3>Email: @Email</h3>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    [SupplyParameterFromQuery]
    public string? Email { get; set; }
}
```

Это позволяет передавать параметры из [Query String](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#query-strings), т.е. страница будет доступна по `/test?email=test@test.com` и свойство `Email` будет содержать переданный email адрес.

Если у вас название парамента в url и в коде не сходится, то вы можете указать любое другое как параметр `Name` в `SupplyParameterFromQuery`, например: `[SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name = "email")`.

Answer (score 1):

Мне нужно было проинжектить NavigationManager:

```
@inject NavigationManager NavManager
...

    /// <summary>
    ////Получаем e-mail пользователя из адресной строки
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>E-mail пользователя, переданный в качестве параметра в адресе</returns>
    private string GetUserEmail()
    {
        var uri = NavManager.ToAbsoluteUri(NavManager.Uri);
        var userEmail = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query).Get("userEmail");

        return userEmail;
    }
```